# Torrent Client that file-maps to pieces

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

I was wondering if there was any torrent client that allows file-mapping to specific pieces, so in an single file, (Say RapSamples.mp3) there are 9 pieces, and the last piece is different, (for example, I add an shout-out to whatever). I know Deluge has the Pieces Plugin but it still seems to do an hash check, any leads?